# how to load a web start application into eclipse rcp

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I have a Webstart Apps/jnlp in which I would like to add into an already made rcp client. Can I integrate the web start application into the RCP so it will appear under the menu toolbar so if it was clicked it will load ithe application.If so How will I go about doing that, would it need to be place into as a plug-in?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this tutorial by Lars Vogel](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&biw=1920&bih=883&q=vogella%20commands%20tutorial&aq=1v&aqi=g-v2g-j2&aql=&oq=vogella%20com) to learn how to use commands in Eclipse RCP (and enable command execution from menus).

Then, in your command handler, write the code that opens the web browser with the url of your application passed as parameter:

```
//Assuming 'url' is the url of your application
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getBrowserSupport().createBrowser(null).openURL(url);
```

Also, check out [this link](http://this%20link) to learn more about Eclipse RCP browser support. Since you didn't specify whether you want this to be opened with an internal or an external browser, you might want to tweak the code I posted.